# How do I create a partial mock for a controller when I'm calling routes?

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-5, mockery, lumen

I'm trying to test a controller method in Lumen by calling `$this->call("GET", $route, $data)`. This calls the `getUserList` method on my controller class.

But I'm having a problem because the `getUserList` method calls some methods on the controller class that I need to mock. I attempted to set up a partial mock for the controller class like this:

```
$controller = Mockery::mock("App\Http\Controllers\MyController[myMethod]");
App::instance("App\Http\Controllers\MyController", $controller);
```

in each test.

My tests look like this:

```
class ControllerTest extends TestCase {
    public function test_1()
    {
        // set some stuff up

        // mock the controller
        $controller = Mockery::mock("App\Http\Controllers\MyController[myMethod]");
        App::instance("App\Http\Controllers\MyController", $controller);

        // call the method
        $result = $this->call("GET", $route, $data);    

        // assert some stuff
    }

    public function test_2()
    {
        // set some stuff up

        // mock the controller
        $controller = Mockery::mock("App\Http\Controllers\MyController[myMethod]");
        App::instance("App\Http\Controllers\MyController", $controller);

        // call the method
        $result = $this->call("GET", $route, $data);    

        // assert some stuff
    }
}
```

This works fine for the first test, but for the second and later ones, the instance that I declared is forgotten.

I've tried a number of different things:

1. creating (or recreating) the mocked class in each test
2. creating a single instance of the mocked class as a property of the test class (initializing it in the constructor or in the `setUp` method) - the hope here was that using a single instance for each test would solve the problem.
3. changing the `call()` method in the tests to an `action()` method (ie. calling the controller method directly instead of via an HTTP request to the route).

But none of these approaches worked.

I *could* rewrite the code so that the code that needs to be mocked is moved to a separate library class which is then mocked & used, but that's adding a layer of complexity. I'm attempting to write a microservice that interfaces with a particular legacy application's database - it only needs to do a small number of things so I don't want to add a whole lot of code here.

Comment: Why are you mocking the controller? You should not mock the controller - there is no need...

Comment: I'm testing a controller method which calls another method which needs to be mocked (accesses some resources that shouldn't be accessed during testing). As I explained in the question, I don't really want to add additional classes to this application - I want it small and simple. I'm less concerned about the "purity" of my MVC architecture that I am about keeping it simple for others on my team to understand & maintain.

Comment: You have controller methods calling other controllers methods? You should also not be doing that. This is why you are running into trouble with your tests. You should be extracting your logic into simple Commands and calling those from your controllers. Much easier to test.

Comment: And it is not about the 'purity' of MVC - it is about writing good testable maintainable code. Calling Controllers from within Controllers is not that - and hence not testable correctly...

Comment: I do understand the importance of this approach for testability - I do it for the applications I work on. In this case, I'm putting together a microservice. There are three routes for querying a legacy database and I'm striving to keep things as simple as possible. There are a number of helper methods which are related to controller actions, so I put them in the controller. I could move them to a separate class, but I feel that's complicating things more than I'd like.

Comment: I'm getting the impression that Lumen is not really a good fit for this project. I find I'm writing something close to a complete Laravel application for a small number of actions - something I haven't had to do with other microservices that I've written based on the Slim framework. Thanks for your comments @TheShiftExchange - they've helped to clarify my thinking on this.